# Finding remote server time

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find out the Remote server time using the two following.

```
$time1 = icm $computerName {Get-Date}
Write-Host $time1
```

and

```
$time1 = ([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime((gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername $computerName).LocalDateTime)
Write-Host $time1
```

The above return only the local time when we use the `ConvertToDateTime()`.

If we don't use it, we get the output as `"20171023053309.931000+000"` which has the server time `"2017 10 23 05 33 09.931000+000"`.

Comment: what is `< computer-name >`? That's a syntax error in Powershell.

Comment: The actual computer name will be the input instead of < computer-name >!

Comment: What time format are you looking for?

Comment: `$time1.ToUniversalTime()`?

Comment: $time1.ToUniversalTime() works perfectly fine!